# How to hide whole loading process of page and show ready page to users?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm having following problem: my PHP page generates navigation menus from db like `<ul>` menus then with the help of JS shows it like multi-level menu. The problem is, it shows whole loading process. At first user sees something like that:

[image]

Then

[image]

How to hide whole loading process of page, or is there any other solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this is done by showing/hiding a div or two over the top of your content. You can get a fancy loading gif from http://www.ajaxload.info/ to get you started. Then you'll want to place a DIV on your page:

```
<div id="loading">
  <p><img src="loading.gif" /> Please Wait</p>
</div>
```

You'll want this hidden by default, so you'd need to add this CSS:

```
#loading { display:none; }
```

You'd also want to setup the display for this too:

```
#loading { display:none; position:fixed; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;
           background-image:url("transparentbg.png"); }
#loading img {position: absolute; left:50%; top:50%}
```

The file `transparentbg.png` would be a 25x25 black PNG set to about 80% opaque. Next you would need a way to show and hide this with jQuery:

```
function showLoading() {
  $("#loading").show();
}

function hideLoading() {
  $("#loading").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

hide it in css,

```
#loading {
  display: block;
  background: url(loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
#container {
  display: none;
}
```

and, in javascript show it again (this code uses jquery)

```
$(function(){
    $('#loading').fadeOut(250, function(){
        $('#container').show();
    });
});
```

of course you can do this like anyhow you want, hide and show anything in css,
then on document ready, switch it over to the content. by hiding the loading div, and showing the content.

Comment: Whole page? How to do it with some animation? Let's say: loading

Comment: It's  not the solution. I wnat to hide while loading

Comment: whole page, part of page, what ever you want, see my edit. it comes down to hiding it at first (css) and showing it after page is ready loading...

Comment: I need to create another div with id loading. I'm not familiar with js. Can we modify this code to use only js, not with html markup? I mean js will do followings without any html markup change: show "loading", then when the page will be ready, it will hide "loading" and show page.

Answer (score 3):

Set the style on `display:none;` until your page is completely loaded.